# CSS - Repeating styled border around heading / HTML

Tags: html, css, layout, border

I've got the following code for my html section

only the first heading creates a border and the rest are all over the place, below is two photos of what it should look like, and what it does look like...

![enter image description here][1]

![enter image description here][2]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Alvaro added to edit now, unsure if thats correct way of doing it though.

Comment: You should try to only put the code in the fiddle that is relevant, taking out the rest of your CSS and HTML. It would also help you in problem solving your own issue

Comment: @Zeaklous been playing around with the code for hours, just cant seem to figure it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a bit messy. But if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/96z7U/3/
These are the changes:

```
<h1 class="titleBorder">Module Details</h1>
```

It had no class.

```
#moduleDetails {
    border-style: solid;
    /*border-width: 1px;*/
    padding: 5px;
}
```

I'm not sure if you intended that border.

And:

```
.titleBorder {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Add float left and width 100%

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be connected with the fact that the content below the heading have the style `float:left` which causes the issue. Try adding the following code before each heading with class 'titleBorder':

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```